# How to add quotes to a datestring notepad++ regex

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, text-editing

I have a huge text files with date strings in the first column. For further processing, I need to have the date strings in double quotation marks:

```
2015-11-11 00:00:00.00,59,...
```

Should end up like this:

```
"2015-11-11 00:00:00.00",59,...
```

I am using NotePad++ and my attempts to find and replace using  wildcards have not resulted in a specific enough solution such that the end quote sometimes ends up in the wrong column. 
Here is what I was using:

```
Find: 2015-.*0,

Replace: "2015-.*0",
```

What would the best way to this be in NotePad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give this one a try:

```
\b\d{4}(-\d\d){2} (\d\d:){2}\d\d\.\d\d
```

I guess (hope) it's not too dense to be readable.

I forgot the replace expression. It should be:

```
"$&"
```

Where $& represents the whole string the regexp matched against.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks for the quick response!